# ¿Cómo se dice “La Playstation” o “El Playstation”?

Tags: género

Una duda que ha surgido con un grupo de personas es con respecto a la conocida consola PlayStation y en cuanto a cómo deberíamos referirnos sobre este objeto.

- Forma larga - “La PlayStation” o “El PlayStation”.
- Forma abreviada - “La Play” o “El Play”.

Entonces aparecieron dos grandes argumentos:

1. Debería ser “la” por el simple hecho de que es una consola y eso lo hace género femenino.
2. Sería “el” porque PlayStation o Play como se le llama también abreviando, serían masculinos.

¿Alguien sabría realmente que es lo correcto y explicar por qué?

Comment: *play* y *playstation* en inglés tendrían género neutro. No veo la forma de poder afirmar que son palabras masculinas.

Answer (score 9):

En el caso de los nombres propios, son los usuarios del lenguaje los que le confieren a la palabra un género, por así decirlo. En este caso, dado que "PlayStation" hace referencia a una consola de videojuegos, se suele usar "la PlayStation" omitiendo la palabra "consola". Así lo podemos ver en ejemplos extraídos del CREA:

> *Toshiba y Sony ya han cooperado en el desarrollo y la producción del procesador para la PlayStation 2.*
>
> La Prensa. Suplemento de Informática, 20/03/2001 (Nicaragua).
>
> ---
>
> *Tras la exposición prolongada a las 16 horas de la primera temporada se han descrito efectos secundarios como un impulso por desempolvar el traje de la comunión o intentos de sustituir la PlayStation 2 por los Juegos Reunidos.*
>
> El País. El País de las Tentaciones, 30/05/2003 (España).

Es posible usar también el nombre propio sin artículo, del mismo modo que no usamos artículo con nuestros propios nombres:

> *Durante 2004 haremos un gran esfuerzo de mercadotecnia para ampliar la base de jugadores en red con PlayStation 2.*
>
> El País, 01/04/2004 (España).

Eso no quita para que se pueda usar, en ocasiones, el artículo masculino si la palabra que se omite se considera otra, como podría ser "el sistema PlayStation". Encontramos también algún caso así:

> *Creo que no sería apropiado introducir un nuevo producto cuando al PlayStation le está yendo muy bien.*
>
> Excélsior, 18/01/1997 (México).

En este caso parece que se refiere a "el producto PlayStation". En todo caso, yo diría que la norma general ahora mismo es usar "la PlayStation" (omitiendo "consola") u omitir el artículo. Suele ser también la tónica general para el resto de consolas de videojuegos:

- La Nintendo DS.
- La Xbox 360.
- La GameCube.
- La Switch/Wii.
- La Dreamcast.
- La Master System II.
- Etc.

Comment: Curioso. Parece entonces que en España todas son femeninas. Aquí siempre se refieren a las consolas en masculino. El nintendo, el xbox (el x), el gamecube, etc. En Colombia se piensa en ellas como en **el video-juego** y por eso el masculino.

Comment: @Charlie esto me suena a lo que hablábamos hace poco sobre la/el URL :-)

Answer (score 5):

La otra vez platicaba con un amigo de las diferencias entre el español de México y el de España, y salió al aire el asunto de las consolas.

En España es *la Xbox, la Playstation, la Wii*, etc. Mientras que en México (y gran parte de Latinoamérica) el género de estas consolas es masculino, por ejemplo *el Xbox, el Wii*. La razón de ser femeninas es en teoría porque se hace alusión a su *hiperónimo*, que es una consola de juegos. En otras variantes del español, yo creo que lo que pasa es un proceso de *lexicalización* (o similar a él) muy rápido, en el cual se considera que todos saben que esa palabra hace referencia a una consola. Por tanto se termina eligiendo el género con respecto a su terminación fonética.

Hay casos similares en el cual no se utiliza el proceso de otorgar género a una palabra según su hiperónimo, y creo que el mejor ejemplo es el siguiente. Por lo general se dice: *una Coca(-Cola)* o *una Pepsi(-Cola)* pero se dice *un 7-up* o *un Sprite*. Ciertos casos contradicen el hecho de que su hiperónimo es de hecho un refresco, una soda o una bebida refrescante.

¿Cuál es el género correcto? Actualmente ambos, según el país donde te encuentres será mejor aceptado. Sin embargo tal vez a la larga termine generalizándose el género masculino o el más acorde a la fonética como pasó con los refrescos.

Answer (score 3):

"PlayStation" es un nombre propio, extranjero para más señas, y por tanto no tiene género *per se*, igual que (por ejemplo) el nombre "Jose".
Lo que le confiere el género es la persona u objeto así llamado. Y así, diremos (mal dicho, porque los nombres propios de personas no suelen llevar artículo, pero es un ejemplo):

- "**el** Jose" si es **un** hombre
- "**la** Jose" si es **una** mujer

En el caso que planteas, por tanto, diremos "**la** PlayStation" porque es **una** videoconsola.

Comment: ¿Pero de todos modos está mal entonces decir “la” también?

Comment: @walen el uso de los artículos no es incorrecto, pero sí que según la zona puede conferirle a la persona ciertas cualidades positivas o negativas (y por lo tanto, es mejor evitar para que nadie lo interprete mal)

Answer (score 3):

En los casos en que utilizamos una marca o unas siglas para referirnos a un objeto, el género suele ser el mismo que el de la palabra que sustituimos con esa marca. En este caso, se trata de una consola de videojuegos: por tanto, sustituimos *la consola* por *la PlayStation*.

Dentro del mismo campo semántico, esto lo vemos con mucha claridad con las siglas PC. En los países en que predomina el uso de la palabra *ordenador* solemos decir *el PC*, mientras que donde es más habitual el uso de *computadora* suele decirse *la PC*.

Comment: En Colombia es _El computador_ y _el play_

Comment: Hace un momento escuchaba en un podcast un diálogo entre una mexicana y un español: "¿Sale usted en la Hola?" "¿En el Hola?" "Sí, en la Hola". Supongo que en España durante un tiempo se usó el anglicismo *magacín* para referirse a las revistas y de ahí que utilicemos el masculino para sus nombres.